# locally, _ is undefined. On my server, 'lodash' is undefined

Tags: javascript, wordpress, lodash, mamp

So, I'm not doing anything fancy at all, it's just a real basic WordPress site. I've included Lodash, and on my local MAMP server, `lodash.throttle` works, but on my EC2 host, `lodash is not defined`.

In the inverse, on my host, `_.throttle` works, but `lodash.throttle` isn't defined.

Has anyone encountered this before? It's *exactly* the same code on both ends.

Comment: check whether lodash is included in the js or the html file. check in network tab  to know the file is loaded correctly or not.

Comment: Yeah, the same file is included in the same spot from the same CDN (cdnjs), from which every other included JS file is working :/